# How to Set Up a Responsive Background-Image with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

Have two div-classes: a `bar` that nests a `menu`

`background-image` isn't properly scaled or responsive when placed in `bar` class, and isn't appearing when placed in the `menu` class, where it seems fitting to style responsively.

Also, the image is png, but gets rendered with white-space in the clear-space … why might this be?

Testing both as inline styles now, but, in an external style sheet nested in a 'css' folder, how can the image be pointed to in an 'img' folder adjacent the path of the 'css' folder?

For Responsiveness…the background-image should scale with the Browser height/width, as appropriate..

Current CSS:

```
.bar {
  position: static;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("img/menu-bar.png");
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" is a wonderfully broad term. What _exactly_ isn't working - please explain your problem in more detail

Comment: background-size:cover????

Comment: Have you made sure the path to the background image is correct?  That's typically the problem with missing background images.

Comment: make sure the background-image url is relative to the css, not the page you're including the css in. [Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url)

Comment: Ok, so it's partially a "relative to the css" issue.. Moved the style to the document, and it worked within the 'bar' class, but it's not appropriately sized.. And it's not working within the 'menu' class, which is probably where it could be made responsive..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking several questions here. So, in order:

By default, `background-image` will be repeated at its actual size. If you want it to scale, you should set the `background-size` and probably disable `background-repeat`. To have the image scale to the size of the container, you can set `background-size: 100% 100%;` or you could use `background-size: cover` to fill the container on the smaller dimension and clip off the rest. The other option is to use `background-size: contain` to avoid clipping the image.

As to the path issue, paths are always relative to the CSS file. So if, as you say, the stylesheet is in a `css` folder adjacent to the `img` folder, you would just set the path relative to the `css` folder.

You final CSS might look something like this:

```
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(../img/menu-bar.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Note that I removed the quotes as they are not necessary.

Finally, if your transparency isn't working then there must be something wrong with the image file itself. CSS has nothing to do with PNG transparency. Make sure your graphics editor is saving the PNG with the appropriate transparency.

Comment: Everything you said makes complete sense, and with these styles placed for the 'bar' CSS, it works perfectly, so thanks for that.. For whatever reason, however, the background-image does not appear when these styles are written for the 'menu' class, which is nested in the 'bar' class.. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Also, the transparency is maintained for the image, it seems to have something to do with the 10% height of the bar, which intentionally causes the rest of the page content to scroll out from above the bar.. This may be fit for another question, but can the 10% height be appropriated for the image and it's transparency?

Comment: I think your issues are related to your positioning and display modes... the `display: inline-block` without a width or height will just be the size of the content, so if you have no content the div will be invisible. You might want to try `display: block` with a width and height. Give the parent `position: relative;` so the child is contained within it.

Comment: Great suggestions, @nullability. I really like the idea to use `background-size: cover;`. That seems to act in a way to alleviate some common issues with `100% 100%`. Thanks again. +1